# Linux Shell script executed but not return to command prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that runs one of the following line

```
sudo -u $USER $SUDOCMD &>>stdout.log
```

The sudo command is a realtime process that print out lots of stuff to the console.

After running the script each time, the script does not return to the command prompt. You have to press enter or ctrl + c to get back to the command prompt.

Is there a way to to do it automatically, so that I can get a return value from the script to decide whether the script runs ok or failed.

thanks.

Comment: You *are* back at the prompt; you're just not seeing a prompt *printed* because a bunch of your program's output went after the prompt, so it's hidden behind all that output.

Comment: This type of thing happens if the script runs background processes that keep printing after the script returns. They write their output after the prompt.

Comment: Maybe the script needs to use the `wait` command so it doesn't exit until all the background processes finish.

Comment: charles barmar , yes, you are right. The process keeps running in the background and print out output to the console. I do not think we need a "solution" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is probably happening here is that your script is printing binary data to the TTY rather than text to standard output/error, and this is hiding your prompt. You can for example try this:

```
$ PS1='\$ '
$ (printf "first line\nsecond line\r" > $(tty)) &>> output.log
```

The second command will result in two lines of output, the second one being "mixed in" with your prompt:

```
first line
$ cond line
```

As you can see the cursor is on the "c", but if you start typing the rest of the line is overwritten. What has happened here is the following:

1. You pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the command, so the cursor moved a line down.
2. The `tty` command prints the path to the terminal file, something like "/dev/pts/1". Writing to this file means that the output does not go to standard output (which is *usually* linked to the terminal) but directly to the terminal.
3. The subshell (similar to running the command in a shell script) ensures that the first redirect isn't overridden by the second one. So the `printf` output goes directly to the terminal, and nothing goes to the output log.
4. The terminal now proceeds to print the `printf` output, which ends in a carriage return. Carriage return moves the cursor to the start of the line you've already written to, so that is where your prompt appears.

By the way:

- `&>>` redirects *both* standard output and standard error, contrary to your filename.
- [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
- I would recommend reading up on [how to put a command in a variable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: this seems not to be the case with this issue. But thanks much for your details and recommendation,